# installed ubuntu 16.04 on hp laptop - wifi not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

There are a few different posts out there for this combination:

Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with wireless adapter made by Qualcomm Atheros A4242x.
Driver ath5k version 4.4.0-31-generic
(above information extracted based on the "sudo lshw -C network" command.

Basically, when I click on the "enable networking" option on the top right hand corner of my screen... and then I select "Enable Wireless"... nothing happens.

Here's what I've tried so far based on other posts that I've seen:

1. In a terminal I ran:

   sudo modprobe ath5k

I didn't get any errors... Disabled networking and reenabled.  No diff.

2. I checked my /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file and there was nothing close to the wifi driver listed there... so I left it alone.
3. I tried to see if it was some form of hardware encryption issue (again, based on another post with similar hardware) and did the following:

   echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf
      sudo modprobe -rfv ath5k
      sudo modprobe -v ath5k

then I tried to restart networking and wifi.  still no go.

I'm currently without a eth cable so I can't connect directly to my modem and get internet access from the laptop in question.  Otherwise, I would have posted all the results here to make your life easier.

But any tips you have would be most appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I also tried to edit the /etc/iftab file because I noticed that the "logical" name of my Wireless interface that is listed when I run "lshw -C network" said "wls1".  I tried to change it to "wlan0"

But after editing the file and restarting networking, I can see that the old name is still there. I also tried to reboot the machine. 
It still shows the same logical name of wls1.  But the /etc/iftab file does have "wlan0".

I did a

```
  grep -ris wls1 /etc/
```

but got no other results.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT 2

In case it helps, I found references to wls1 in a file "/run/udev/data/n3"
and it has entries like:

```
       E:DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wls1
       E:INTERFACE=wls1
       E:ID_NET_NAME_SLOT=wls1
```

etc.

EDIT 3

Results of "rfkill list all" command:

```
   0: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
   1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: yes
            Hard blocked: yes
```

And the results from "dmesg | grep ath" command:

```
 [12.164885] ath5k 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
 [12.165046] ath5k 0000:02:00.0: registered as 'phy0'
 [12.790152] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x64
 [12.790157] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
 [12.790160] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
 [12.790162] ath: Regpair used: 0x64
 [12.829548] ath5k: phy0: Atheros AR2425 chip found (MAC: 0xe2, PHY: 0x70)
 [12.873941] ath5k: 000:02:00.0 wls1: reanmed from wlan0
```

Note: I did revert the changes I made to /etc/iftab file with the logical name because it didn't seem to have any effect. 
Maybe that's what the last log entry is showing?

Comment: What does this tell us? `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep ath` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 Please see edit 3

Comment: *Hard blocked:yes* suggests that the hardware switch or wireless key combination is set to disable the wireless. Please find it and switch it.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but can you expand a little?  Im a little lost

Comment: Where would this hardware switch be located?

Comment: Which model HP laptop is it?

Comment: @chili55 I found the hardware toggle!  Thanks.  That worked.